# Unable to save Excel worksheet using C# and Syncfusion

Tags: c#, excel, syncfusion

I am trying to generate an Excel spreadsheet from SQL Server using a datatable.  I am not getting any error messages but when I try to save the workbook it is not showing up on my computer.  I am using the following code:

```
using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())
{
    //Initialize application
    IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;

    //Set the default application version as Excel 2016
    application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2016;

    //Create a new workbook
    IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Create(1);

    //Access first worksheet from the workbook instance
    IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

    //Export DataTable to worksheet
    //Get data from DataTable
    //DataTable dataTable = GetDataTable();
    ////Export DataTable to worksheet with column name and start range
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(PHLIP251, connection);
    PHLIP251Datatable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

    worksheet.ImportDataTable(PHLIP251Datatable, true, 1, 1);
    worksheet.UsedRange.AutofitColumns();

    //Save the workbook to disk in xlsx format
    workbook.SaveAs(@"Documents\\" + "DMBErrors.xlsx");
    connection.Close();
```

Comment: Which part of this is related to Syncfusion?

Comment: Are you checking the *correct* folder? `Documents\DMBErrors.xlsx` is a relative path

Comment: Yes, I am checking the correct folder.  I also used the search function to locate the DMBErrors.xlsx file and it is not on my computer anywhere.

Comment: All of the code is from Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

The generated Excel file will be located in the Documents folder created in the bin->Debug folder of the sample. Please use the below code snippet in run-time to get the location of the file.

```
System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"Documents\\" + "DMBErrors.xlsx");
```